I have CSV with 10 columns, one of which is an XML field. When I read this data into IDQ (Informatica Developer)as source it splits the xml into new c
I have CSV with 10 columns, one of which is an XML field. When I read this data into IDQ (Informatica Developer)as source it splits the xml into new columns, instead of keeping it in the one field.enter image description here
How to load XML data in to single column

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
